# MySQL Escaping Single Quotes With mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I am inserting into a database with mysqli_real_escape_string, I am finding that my single quotes are been escaped with `\\` rather than `\` which is causing my query to fail. See below:

**NOTE:** $link is my db connection var.

```
$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, "BEGIN testing quotes - don't use quotes END");
$query = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('".$string."')";
```

When I echo out my query, I get:

`INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('BEGIN testing quotes - don\\'t use quotes END')`

which is causing a SQL syntax error. I cannot seem to find a setting anywhere that can change this. If I copy the echo'd query into MySQL workbench and remove a `\`, the query insert's perfectly.

I have had a look through Stack Overflow and cannot find anything relating to this, and also searched through Google with no luck.

I have many queries that need escaping across my entire website. Could a setting be set to automatically apply escaping of strings pre-insert without having to go through and update all my variables? If not, Is there anyway I can alter the mysqli_real_escape_string function without having to manually check every string I insert for single quotes etc?

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: use prepared statements

Comment: don't. Use prepared statements instead look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Sounds like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on. Don't do that. And do use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Magic Quotes are disabled, checked that one. Stripslashes worked.

Comment: $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, stripslashes("BEGIN testing quotes - don't use quotes END"));

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As Krishna Gupta suggested, stripslashes resolved my issue:

`$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, stripslashes("BEGIN testing quotes - don't use quotes END"));`

Thanks.